# Vulkan vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR returns VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT

Tags: c++, vulkan

For a programming project this semester I'm looking to create a demo using the Vulkan API. Using online resources I've gotten as far as initializing an instance and creating a logical device, but I'm stuck on creating a surface.

Creating the device:

```cpp
[...]

uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

const char* const* _ppExtensionNames = NULL;
std::vector<const char *> extNames;
std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> extProps(extensionCount);
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL, &extensionCount, extProps.data());
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < extensionCount; i++) {
    extNames.push_back(extProps[i].extensionName);
}


VkInstanceCreateInfo instInfo = {};
instInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
instInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
instInfo.flags = VkInstanceCreateFlags();
instInfo.enabledExtensionCount = extensionCount;
instInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extNames.data();
instInfo.enabledLayerCount  = static_cast<uint32_t>(layers.size());
instInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames  = layers.data();
// Create the Vulkan instance.
VkResult res;

res = vkCreateInstance(&instInfo, NULL, &vulkanData.instance);
```

Creating the surface:

```
VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR createInfo;
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
createInfo.hwnd = vulkanData.window;
createInfo.hinstance = vulkanData.connection;

vulkanData.surface = VkSurfaceKHR();
VkResult res = vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR(vulkanData.instance, &createInfo,
    nullptr, &vulkanData.surface);
if (res != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to create window surface!");
}
```

Visual Studio's inspector shows that `extNames` holds `"VK_KHR_surface"` after calling `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()`.

Vulkan's demos run fine, so I would assume my driver isn't the issue.
I'm trying to run this on a GTX 960M (with Optimus, no option to disable it)
Also updated to the most recent driver today.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "*`extNames` holds `"VK_KHR_surface"`*" Well, does it hold the actual extension you're trying to use? Namely, VK_KHR_win32_surface.

Comment: @NicolBolas ah yeah that makes sense. But yes, that's in there too. Actually- my code runs fine now somehow without me making any changes..

Comment: Why are you enabling every single extension, rather than the ones you're specifically targeting?  Is it possible that some of the extensions are mutually exclusive?